# ¿Cómo construir controles html dinamicos en Vue Js a partir de un Json?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, componentes

buen día Comunidad.

Necesito su ayuda para construir controles HTML de forma dinamica en VUE a partir de un JSON.

Actualmente tengo un ejercicio hecho, tengo un template html que renderiza una lista de controles input a partir de los parametros de un JSON. Sin embargo yo quiero construir más controles, no sólo inputs.

**Mi objetivo es** recibir en el Json el tipo de control que debo construir junto con sus parametros. Por ejemplo si en el json viene un control del tipo select debo constuir un select, si viene un control tipo textarea debo construir un textarea y así sucesivamente.

Dejen sus ideas de solución, gracias.

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Hola Mundo',
      fields: [
        {
          "name": "fechaRegistro",
          "label": "Fecha de Registro",
          "type": "date",
          "placeholder": 'Ingresa Fecha'
        },
        {
          "name": "nombreDeUsuario",
          "label": "Nombre de Usuario",
          "type": "text",
          "placeholder": "Ingresa Usuario"
        },
        {
          "name": "passwordUsuario",
          "label": "Password",
          "type": "password",
          "placeholder": "Contraseña"
        },
        {
          "name": "adjuntarArchivo",
          "label": "Adjuntar",
          "type": "file"
        },
        {
          "name": "activo",
          "label": "Activo",
          "type": "checkbox"
        },
        {
          "name": "roles",
          "label": "Roles",
          "type": "multiSelect",
          "sortedByKey": false,
          "options": [{
              "name": "admin",
              "label": "Admin"
            },
            {
              "name": "user",
              "label": "User"
            },
            {
              "name": "guest",
              "label": "Invitado"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

a {
  color: #42b983;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    <form>
      <ul id="controles">
        <li v-for="field in fields" :key="field">
          <label :for="field.name">{{field.label}}</label>
          <input :id="field.name" :type="field.type" :placeholder="field.placeholder">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

No veo del todo la dificultad, quizás sea porque no he entendido del todo el problema. Igualmente me parece un ejercicio muy interesante. Si no me equivoco quieres recorrer los elementos de un json e ir creando controles según ese json. Diría lo que pides es demasiado genérico, por que no especificas que controles quieres que se puedan renderizar. Deberías intentar ir poco a poco con una prueba de concepto. Vamos a hacer un ejemplo con un input y un button. Prueba lo siguiente:

- Añade los controles que quieras usar dentro de la etiqueta li.
- Añade el atributo v-if para distinguir el tipo de control que quieres renderizar y añade a tu listado un campo con el tipo de control.

Algo así:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    <form>
      <ul id="controles">
        <li v-for="field in fields" :key="field">
          <label :for="field.name">{{field.label}}</label>
          <input v-if="field.controlType == 'input'"  :id="field.name" :type="field.type" :placeholder="field.placeholder">
          <button v-if="field.controlType == 'button'" :id="field.name"> {{ field.text }}</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Refínalo un poco, esto es solo un ejemplo rápido. Yo no uso comparaciones en el propio html, veo mejor hacerlas en métodos. Si ves que eso te sirve empieza a añadir otros controles como textarea o un select. También puedes condicionar el label según el tipo de controles para evitar poner un label a un botón. Para ello puedes hacerte un método que compruebe el tipo y te diga si ese tipo debe llevar label.

Como he dicho me parece interesante, dime si te sirve y si no es el caso danos más datos para poder ayudarte. Podrías hacerte un jsfiddle de ejemplo para que podamos hacer forks con ideas.

Un saludo!

Comment: Es correcto, quiero construir controles de formulario diferentes a partir de un json. Ahora tengo dos dudas, 1- ¿cómo se harían las comparaciones con un método? 2- ¿cómo podría separar cada control html en un componente diferente e irlos llamando según la condición? Gracias

Comment: Me parece un poco abusivo, deberías intentar resolverlo tu. En lugar de hacerte el código te daré unas pistas.
 1. En el cuerpo del script debes introducir el bloque "methods" y en el creas una función a la que le pases el parámetro a comparar y que devuelva el resultado de la comparación. En el template solo tienes que llamar a esa función.
 2. Eso es mas largo de explicar, pero solo tienes que hacer un archivo .vue nuevo similar al que has hecho y luego importarlo en este para usarlo. Tienes más información en la documentación de vue https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html